# Global Resources and Windows Azure

Tags: globalization, azure

My ASP.Net 3.5 SP 1 MVC 1.0 web application uses Resources (resx) in several languages. The default language is English.

My resources pick up the right language from the current thread, which I set before trying to display any resource.

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(Model.CurrentCultureCode);
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(Model.CurrentCultureCode);
```

All this worked fine until I started migrating to Windows Azure.

In Windows Azure, the same code seems to be stuck on English, event though Model.CurrentCultureCode has the correct value.

Anyone else is experimenting something like this when migrating to Windows Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by moving my resource files from the separate library where they were to the same WebRole project where the website is. I also placed my resource files in the App_GlobalResources folder.

Although my solution now works, this doesn't explain why the resources files where not working properly in a separate library. Let me know if you can figure that one out.